# php. mkdir(). set $mode with leading zero from string variable

Tags: php

Okay, we have example at php.net:

```php
mkdir($structure, 0777, true);
```

How to set `0777` integer from variable?

I have environment variable, for example `PERMISSIONS=0755`. And `0755` is a string.
As I can see there is no way to convert string to int with leading zero.

So is there any way to set permissions from variable?

```php
define('PERMISSIONS', '0755');
mkdir($structure, PERMISSIONS, true); // bad!
mkdir($structure, intval(PERMISSIONS), true); // bad too!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function [`octdec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php):

```
$permissions = octdec($_SERVER['PERMISSONS']);
mkdir($structure, $permissions, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

define initial set as integer.

```
define('PERMISSIONS', 0755);
```

OR

```
define('PERMISSIONS', '0755');
$permission = intval(PERMISSIONS);
mkdir($structure, $permission, true);
```

Comment: what difference between `$permission = intval(PERMISSIONS);` and `mkdir($structure, intval(PERMISSIONS), true);`? And I can't set OS environment variable as integer.